# Why DNS resolution support is enabled for inter-region VPC peering connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

Probably this is not the right place to ask :)

I have implemented the inter-region VPC peering connection.

In the documentation of AWS, They have mentioned below thing

> You cannot enable DNS resolution support for an inter-region VPC
> peering connection.

[Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/modify-peering-connections.html)

But i have verified that this is working fine and i am able to resolve DNS in inter-region VPC peering connection.

So my question is whether is it enabled by default or their documentation is wrong?

Another strange thing is that from AWS console, *This feature is disabled for inter-region VPC peering communication.*

[image: AWS Console]

I am confused about how to get rid of this.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You know that the DNS resolution that this article talks about is peer1 resolving **public** hostnames from peer2 to **private** IP addresses, yes? Is that what you tested?

Comment: Yes I have tested using private IP and public IP both

Comment: Do you mean that inside of peer VPC #1 in region #1 you name-resolved a **public** hostname in peer VPC #2 in region #2 and it resolved to the **private** IP of that host?

Comment: How I tested is, I have created route53 record set which points to the private IP of VPC #2 in region #2. And from VPC #1 in region #1 i am able to resolve the *private* IP using that record set. Which should not be the case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS recently brought support for this: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/11/announcing-support-for-dns-resolution-over-inter-region-vpc-peering/

That's why it is working fine now. I guess the document was not timely updated.